# How to rewrite a URL to a domain living in a subdirectory of the main domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I've added a 2nd domain in my hosting account, and .htaccess handles requests to this 2nd domain. However, a problem arises if the URL ends with a folder name and without a trailing slash. The resulting URL will contain the domain + the subdirectory (in effect, twice the domain name).

For example, `http://domain2.com/demo` is rewritten to `http://domain2.com/domain2.com/demo/`.

There is no probem if the URL already has a trailing slash, example: `http://domain2.com/demo/`.

The directory structure in my account is such that the files for that second domain live in a subdirectory of the main domain.

```
- main-domain.com
    - public_html
        - domain2.com
```

The .htaccess resides in the public_html folder and file contains this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/domain2.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain2.com/$1 [L]
```

I've tried many variations of these lines but I either get the same results or a server error.